# How to get the return value of xcodebuild?

Tags: xcodebuild

I'm using xcodebuild inside a bash script on a continuous integration server.

I would like to know when a build as failed in the script, so I can exit prematurely from it and mark the build as failed.

xcodebuild displays a BUILD FAILED message to the console, but I don't succeed in getting a return value.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I solved my problem using this command: xcodebuild -... || exit 1

Comment: This is the most clean answer. thnx Mike ;)

Comment: What a genius! Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the "$?" variable to get the return code of the previous command.

```
xcodebuild -...
if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Failed"
fi
```

Answer (score 15):

`xcodebuild` always returns 0, regardless of the actual test result. You should check for either `** BUILD FAILED **` or `** BUILD SUCCEEDED **` in the output to know whether tests pass or not.

Comment: How exactly we can check those statuses ? They are not like exit codes AFAIK

Answer (score 8):

Xcodebuild can return any of the error codes listed below and not restricted to EX_OK (or int 0).

However, I learnt from solution provided by Dmitry and modified as following. It works for me and I hope it could be helpful.

```
xcodebuild -project ......
     if test $? -eq 0
     then
        echo "Success"
     else
        echo "Failed"
     fi
```

## Error codes

The following are the error codes that can be [returned by sysexits](https://web.archive.org/web/20150318161415/https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sysexits.3.html) <sup>[archive](https://archive.is/LV9cB)</sup>:

- **`EX_OK`** (0): Successful exit.
- **`EX_USAGE`** (64): The command was used incorrectly, e.g., with the wrong number of arguments, a bad flag, a bad syntax in a parameter, or whatever.
- **`EX_DATAERR`** (65): The input data was incorrect in some way.  This should only be used for user's data and not system files.
- **`EX_NOINPUT`** (66): An input file (not a system file) did not exist or was not readable.  This could also include errors like ``No message'' to a mailer (if it cared to catch it).
- **`EX_NOUSER`** (67): The user specified did not exist.  This might be used for mail addresses or remote logins.
- **`EX_NOHOST`** (68): The host specified did not exist.  This is used in mail addresses or network requests.
- **`EX_UNAVAILABLE`** (69): A service is unavailable.  This can occur if a support program or file does not exist.  This can also be used as a catchall message when something you wanted to do doesn't work, but you don't know why.
- **`EX_SOFTWARE`** (70): An internal software error has been detected.  This should be limited to non-operating nonoperating operating system related errors as possible.
- **`EX_OSERR`** (71): An operating system error has been detected.  This is intended to be used for such things as `cannot fork'',`cannot create pipe'', or the like.  It includes things like getuid returning a user that does not exist in the passwd file.
- **`EX_OSFILE`** (72): Some system file (e.g., /etc/passwd, /var/run/utmp, etc.) does not exist, cannot be opened, or has some sort of error (e.g., syntax error).
- **`EX_CANTCREAT`** (73): A (user specified) output file cannot be created.
- **`EX_IOERR`** (74): An error occurred while doing I/O on some file.
- **`EX_TEMPFAIL`** (75): Temporary failure, indicating something that is not really an error.  In send-mail, sendmail, mail, this means that a mailer (e.g.) could not create a connection, and the request should be reattempted later.
- **`EX_PROTOCOL`** (76): The remote system returned something that was ``not possible'' during a protocol exchange.
- **`EX_NOPERM`** (77): You did not have sufficient permission to perform the operation.  This is not intended for file system problems, which should use **`EX_NOINPUT`** or **`EX_CANTCREAT`**, but rather for higher level permissions.
- **`EX_CONFIG`** (78): Something was found in an unconfigured or misconfigured state.

For more info [click here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110348/how-do-i-get-the-list-of-exit-codes-and-or-return-codes-and-meaning-for-a-comm).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's not because of the xcodebuild not returning non-zero when build failed. Your shell script continuing to run regardless of the returning-error line might be the result of that you didn't run the script with a "-e" option.

Try put **#!/bin/bash -e** ahead of the script file.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can always check the exist value for the last run process in Unix bash by:

```
$ echo $?
```

where `$?` is a built-in placeholder of the exist value of last executed command. For more details about other bash's built-in variables see [here](http://linuxsig.org/files/bash_scripting.html).

So, first run your command you want to investigate its return code, then run echo as above.

Answer (score -1):

Whether the compiled product （.a or .ipa file）exists