# xcodebuild and bash command response

Tags: xcode, bash, command-line, xcodebuild

I use xcodebuild to build my app from a script on a build server. The build server is reporting success when the build has actually failed, so I'm attempting to improve the script.

The bit I'm having some trouble with, is getting the errors and warnings from the xcodebuild command.

Eg, I've faked an error by removing some images on disk, and not the project file. If I run xcodebuild, I get this output at the end:

```
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
CopyPNGFile build/Release-iphoneos/TT.app/settingscreen.png Resources/Images/helpscreens/settingscreen.png
CopyPNGFile build/Release-iphoneos/TT.app/settingscreen.png Resources/Images/helpscreens/settingscreen.png
(2 failures)
```

So I would assume I could grep for 'BUILD FAILED' from the output. But no such luck. I'm going along the lines of this:

```
OUTPUT=`${XCODEBUILD} -target "$TARGET" -configuration "$CONFIGURATION"`
ANY_FAILURES=`echo "$OUTPUT" | grep -c "BUILD FAILED"`

if [ "$ANY_FAILURES" -gt "0" ]; then
   #...code here if failure...
fi
```

But it's not having it. If I try a build and output to /dev/null, like so

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -target TT -configuration Release > /dev/null
```

Then I still see:

```
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
CopyPNGFile build/Release-iphoneos/TT.app/settingscreen.png Resources/Images/helpscreens/settingscreen.png
CopyPNGFile build/Release-iphoneos/TT.app/settingscreen.png Resources/Images/helpscreens/settingscreen.png
(2 failures)
```

So it seems I can't seem to get a reference to this bit of text that is output.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the return value of xcodebuild?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363459/how-to-get-the-return-value-of-xcodebuild)

Comment: msgs like 'BUILD FAILED' are usually sent to stderr. Try `...-configuration "$CONFIGURATION" 2>&1` in your cmd. Good luck.

Comment: Very good. So 2>&1 combined stderr with stdout. Nice one, that worked. Move this to an answer to get yourself some points.