# OSX/Bash - detecting build failure

Tags: bash, xcodebuild

Using Xcodebuild directly from bash, how would one detect a failure? the exit code is always 0 regardless. I realize there's an "FAILED" or "SUCCEEDED" textural output, but isn't there a more elegant way?

Also, I sometimes use "make" (especially with my Qt based builds). Is there a way to detect make has failed from the build script?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363459/how-to-get-the-return-value-of-xcodebuild/10808467#10808467 ?

Comment: so xcodebuild <param> <param> ....   || exit 1  would exit the script with exit code 1 upon failure? isn't that dependent on xcodebuild actually giving out an exit code >0 when failing? i thought it doesn't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it depends on the version of Xcode or possibly how it fails. This is what I get when I check $? after some include files can't be found:

```
davidb@DavidBs-Mobile-Macintosh:~/Source/icanvas/iCanvas-project (release/icanvas-1.9 %) $ xcodebuild
...
/Users/davidb/Source/icanvas/iCanvas-project/iCanvas-target/iPhone/ConversationViewController.m:21:9: fatal error: 'CanvasKit/CKActionSheetWithBlocks.h' file not found
#import "CanvasKit/CKActionSheetWithBlocks.h"
        ^
1 error generated.
...
** BUILD FAILED **
...
(5 failures)
davidb@DavidBs-Mobile-Macintosh:~/Source/icanvas/iCanvas-project (release/icanvas-1.9 %) $ echo $?
65
```

Answer (score 6):

xcodebuild always returns 0 even when the build fails. To detect errors, you could use a script like this:

```
build_errors_file=build_errors.log

# Pipe errors to file
xcodebuild 2>$build_errors_file

errors=`grep -wc "The following build commands failed" $build_errors_file`
if [ "$errors" != "0" ]
then
    echo "BUILD FAILED. Error Log:"
    cat $build_errors_file
    rm $build_errors_file
    exit 1
fi
rm $build_errors_file

# ... continue
```

I verified that ** BUILD FAILED ** will not be printed when running xcodebuild with the archive option, so it seems that the string to look for is 'The following build commands failed'.

Comment: thanks for this. I also tried the word count on just the string "error" and it seems to be sufficient. (unless all your classes or something have the word "error" on it)

Answer (score 0):

The exit code is not always 0.

I assume you were running the xcodebuild from a shell script.

You may try put **#!/bin/bash -e** ahead of your script file.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40808843/2705627