# Xcode test failing does not failed Github action pipeline

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, xctest, xcodebuild, github-actions

I have a Github Action pipeline:

```
name: default

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: macOS-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: CocoaPod Install
      run: pod install
    - name: Force xcode 11
      run: sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_11.1.app
    - name: Test
      run: ./pipelines.sh test
    - name: Save report
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
      with:
        name: test_report
        path: ./Test
```

And a script Shell:

```
function test
{
    xcodebuild \
       -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace \
       -scheme DEBUG\ -\ MyApp \
       -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11' \
       test
}
```

My problem is when i run my pipeline with failing test, the pipeline is marked as PASSED, which is a problem...

I have also check with fastlane, failing test does not fail the pipeline.

How can I make my pipeline as FAIL when test does not pass?

Cf screenshot for fastlane: 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return a non-zero value to fail the step. 
Try adding this to the `xcodebuild` command.

```
xcodebuild -... || exit 1
```

There are some other solutions besides this at the following question. 
[How to get the return value of xcodebuild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363459/how-to-get-the-return-value-of-xcodebuild)

**Update:** Based on your comments that you would like steps afterwards to complete you can do the following.

Change your script to set an output containing the result of the `xcodebuild` command.

```
    xcodebuild \
       -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace \
       -scheme DEBUG\ -\ MyApp \
       -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11' \
       test
    echo "::set-output name=result::$?"
```

Add an `id` to the step where this script is executed.

```
    - name: Test
      id: xcodebuild
      run: ./pipelines.sh test
```

At the end of your workflow you can check if the tests did not pass and fail the workflow.

```
      - name: Check Tests Passed
        if: steps.xcodebuild.outputs.result != 0
        run: exit 1
```

Comment: When i make it ```xcodebuild -... || exit 1```, commands after this line are not executed if i have some

Comment: Step `Save report` is not executed in the pipeline

Comment: @KevinABRIOUX Updated the answer with a solution to allow further steps to execute and fail afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you're using xcbeautify in your GitHub action to clean up the output of xcodebuild, you can do the following to see the error from the xcodebuild step.

Prepend `set -o pipefail &&`  before your xcodebuild command.

eg:

```
set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace <your workspace>.xcworkspace -scheme "$SCHEME" -derivedDataPath /tmp/derivedData -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,id=$DEVICE_ID" build-for-testing | xcbeautify --renderer github-actions
```

In GitHub you should see a red cross next to the step that failed, in my case it's the `Build Package for Testing` step.

[image: GitHub Action output when step fails]