# How to stop xcodebuild tests execute after first fail

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, xctest, xcodebuild

I have about 300 UI XCTest tests which i want run in every pull request.
I use some command, like it:

```
xcodebuild \
  -project App.xcodeproj \
  -scheme App \
  -sdk iphonesimulator \
  -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8,OS=15.0' \
  test
```

But i want stopping after first failed (for save time in build server). Have any way to do it?

**Update:**
xcodebuild have't any flag for this.
Now i try get result stream, and check that one test is failed.

Answer (score -1):

Add this lines to your script:

```
if test $? -eq 0
then
   echo "xcodebuild succeeded"
else
   echo "xcodebuild failed with " + $?
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Can you pls add more description about how it work?

Comment: $? is a global variable with the result code of the last executed command.
Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363459/how-to-get-the-return-value-of-xcodebuild

Comment: But it wait result all tests, i want stop run after first fail